# Mysql JDBC - not entering ResultSet + incorrect no. of rows

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, jdbc

I came across a problem with going through a ResultSet I'm generating from my MySQL db. My query should return at most one row per table (I'm looping through several tables searching by employee number). I've entered data in some of the tables; but my test o/p says that the resultset contains 0 rows and doesn't go through the ResultSet at all. The o/p line it's supposed to print never appears. It was in a while loop before I realised that it'd be returning at most one row, at which point I just swapped the while(rs.next()) for an if(rs.first()). Still no luck. Any suggestions?
My code looks like this:

```
try
{
    rsTablesList = stmt.executeQuery("show tables;");

    while(rsTablesList.next())
    {
       String tableName = rsTablesList.getString(1); 

       //checking if that table is a non-event table; loop is skipped in such a case
       if(tableName.equalsIgnoreCase("emp"))
       {
           System.out.println("NOT IN EMP");
           continue;
       }

        System.out.println("i'm in " + tableName); //tells us which table we're in

        int checkEmpno = Integer.parseInt(empNoLbl.getText()); //search key


        Statement s = con.createStatement();
        query = "select 'eventname','lastrenewaldate', 'expdate' from " + tableName + " where 'empno'=" + checkEmpno + ";"; // eventname,
        System.out.println("query is \n\t" + query + "");
        rsEventDetails = s.executeQuery(query) ; 

        System.out.println("query executed\n");

        //next two lines for the number of rows
        rsEventDetails.last();
        System.out.println("no. of rows is " + rsEventDetails.getRow()+ "\n\n");

            if(rsEventDetails.first())
            {

                System.out.println("inside the if");

                // i will add the row now
                System.out.println("i will add the row now");
               // cdTableModel.addRow(new Object[] {evtname,lastRenewalDate,expiryDate}); 
            }



    }

}
```

My output looks like this:

I'm in crm

query is

```
select 'eventname','lastrenewaldate', 'expdate' from crm where 'empno'=17;
```

query executed

no. of rows is 0

I'm in dgr

query is

```
select 'eventname','lastrenewaldate', 'expdate' from dgr where 'empno'=17;
```

query executed

no. of rows is 0

NOT IN EMP

I'm in eng_prof

query is

```
select 'eventname','lastrenewaldate', 'expdate' from eng_prof where 'empno'=17;
```

query executed

no. of rows is 0

I'm in frtol

query is

```
select 'eventname','lastrenewaldate', 'expdate' from frtol where 'empno'=17;
```

query executed

no. of rows is 0

(and so on, upto 17 tables.)

The '17' in the query is the empno that I've pulled from the user.
The thing is that I've already entered data in the first two tables, crm and dgr. The same query in the command line interface works; this morning, I tried the program out and it returned data for the one table that had data in it (crm). The next time onwards, nothing.

Context: I'm working on a school project to create some software for my dad's office, it'll help them organise the training etc schedules for the employees. (a little like Google Calendar I guess.) I'm using Netbeans and Mysql on Linux Mint. There are about 17 tables in the database. The user selects an employee name and the program searches for all entries in the database that correspond to an 'event' (my generic name for a test/training/other required event) and puts them into a JTable.

Comment: Don't use quotes around the column or table names. If you need to escape some of them use backticks. So using `where 'empno'=17` translates to: get me all records where the string `empno` is equal to the number `17` which is obviously always `false`.

Comment: @juergend Actually I had a problem with that earlier, when I was creating the query without the single quotes. It would return an error saying that no such column <column-name> was found. A few posts on here with the same problem concluded that this was the way to make it work. My error disappeared, so I thought it had solved the problem. Is this a form of escaping them like you said? I'll change over to backticks in that case..

Comment: \`columnName\` instead of 'columnName' is the way to go

Comment: @nailgun okay, thank you! I'll make the change. :)

Comment: @juergend just saw the second part, thank you for the clear explanation! Got it. I have to go to bed now, I'll test it out in the morning and let you know what I find!

Comment: @juergend I switched all those single quotes round to backticks and it works perfectly! Thank you so much.

Comment: @nailgun I couldn't tag you in my comment above, so here it is! Your suggestion worked out great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The single quotes around the column names and table name in the creation of the query seem to have caused the problem. On changing them to backticks, retrieval works fine and the data comes in as expected.

Thank you, @juergend (especially for the nice explanation) and @nailgun!